# *ngFor doesn't work inside modal (angular 10 ionic 5)

Tags: ngfor, ionic5, angular10

I faced an issue inside my project, *ngFor doesn't work inside the modal component, and works anywhere else. I import BrowserModule in the app component, and commonModule elsewhere.
There is no spelling mistakes.
I am sure the declarative is clearly declared.

The error is:

> Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found the answer in this link:
[Add the component to your app.module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62808649/9569695)
Where you should add the Modal component in the root app module:
First import the Modal page in your app.module,

```
import {ModalPage} from "./home/modal.page"
```

then declares it inside declarations and entryComponents

```
declarations: [AppComponent,ModalPage],

entryComponents: [ModalPage],
```